# What SQL query can I use to retrieve the latest entry for a particular item code and location from the 'PriceHistory' table?

Tags: sql-server

I got a mssql table name PriceHistory, the data like below

| DocDate | DocNo | ItemCode | Location | Qty | UnitPrice | AccNo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/05/23 | I-00012 | CodeA | HQ | 8 | 2.50 | 300/A01 |
| 02/05/23 | P-62510 | CodeB | BR | 4 | 3.80 | 300/A15 |
| 08/05/23 | I-05478 | CodeA | BR | 6 | 2.50 | 400/B11 |
| 10/05/23 | I-15478 | CodeC | BR | 15 | 1.80 | 300/F04 |
| 15/05/23 | S-65741 | CodeA | HQ | 2 | 2.50 | 300/G12 |
| 20/05/23 | P-14785 | CodeC | HQ | 1 | 1.90 | 400/B03 |
| 01/06/23 | I-25413 | CodeA | BR | 20 | 2.40 | 300/A10 |
| 02/06/23 | I-23061 | CodeB | HQ | 3 | 3.80 | 301/A05 |

How to get latest DocDate data for "ItemCode and Location", like result below, thank you.

| DocDate | DocNo | ItemCode | Location | Qty | UnitPrice | AccNo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/06/23 | I-25413 | CodeA | BR | 20 | 2.40 | 300/A10 |
| 02/05/23 | P-62510 | CodeB | BR | 4 | 3.80 | 300/A15 |
| 10/05/23 | I-15478 | CodeC | BR | 15 | 1.80 | 300/F04 |
| 15/05/23 | S-65741 | CodeA | HQ | 2 | 2.50 | 300/G12 |
| 02/06/23 | I-23061 | CodeB | HQ | 3 | 3.80 | 301/A05 |
| 20/05/23 | P-14785 | CodeC | HQ | 1 | 1.90 | 400/B03 |

Comment: This is a widely answered typical question in the [greatest-n-per-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) tag. Take a peek.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```sql
select top 1 with ties *
from (
    VALUES  (N'01/05/23', N'I-00012', N'CodeA', N'HQ', 8, 2.50, N'300/A01')
    ,   (N'02/05/23', N'P-62510', N'CodeB', N'BR', 4, 3.80, N'300/A15')
    ,   (N'08/05/23', N'I-05478', N'CodeA', N'BR', 6, 2.50, N'400/B11')
    ,   (N'10/05/23', N'I-15478', N'CodeC', N'BR', 15, 1.80, N'300/F04')
    ,   (N'15/05/23', N'S-65741', N'CodeA', N'HQ', 2, 2.50, N'300/G12')
    ,   (N'20/05/23', N'P-14785', N'CodeC', N'HQ', 1, 1.90, N'400/B03')
    ,   (N'01/06/23', N'I-25413', N'CodeA', N'BR', 20, 2.40, N'300/A10')
    ,   (N'02/06/23', N'I-23061', N'CodeB', N'HQ', 3, 3.80, N'301/A05')
) t (DocDate,DocNo,ItemCode,Location,Qty,UnitPrice,AccNo)
order by row_number() over(partition by itemcode, location order by convert(datetime,docdate, 3) desc)
```

This generates a row_number which orders by datetime and partitions by your code and location. Top 1 with ties fetches all row_numbers with value = 1.

You can also do it more standard and wrap the query into a subquery and do where rownum = 1

Comment: Replace the value thing with your table name :)